# Reflections in a API sharing same package

Tags: api, kotlin, reflection

So i'm messing around with Reflections in my API for a plugin system and its all working but once i have 2 jars using the same API it seems to use the same packages as shown below

[DiamondBank] and [UpdateNotifier] are two separate jars

```
[14:36:38] [Server thread/INFO]: com.cube.notifier
[14:36:38] [Server thread/INFO]: [UpdateNotifier] Registered 3 Commands.
[14:36:38] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
[14:36:38] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
[14:36:38] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
[14:36:39] [Server thread/INFO]: [DiamondBank] Enabling DiamondBank v1.1
[14:36:39] [Server thread/INFO]: [DiamondBank] Starting DiamondBank
[14:36:39] [Server thread/INFO]: [DiamondBank] Registered 2 Events.
[14:36:39] [Server thread/INFO]: org.cube.diamondbank
[14:36:42] [Server thread/INFO]: [DiamondBank] Registered 3 Commands.
[14:36:42] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
[14:36:42] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
[14:36:42] [Server thread/INFO]: package com.cube.notifier.commands
```

Now i tried to hardcode the path per plugin using a string but i get the same result but it prints out the correct location as seen above

This is my method that loads the commands

```
 val config = ConfigurationBuilder()
        .addScanners(
            SubTypesScanner(false),
            TypeAnnotationsScanner(),
            MethodAnnotationsScanner()
        )
        .addUrls(MinecraftCommand::class.java.getResource(""))


    println(packageName)
    val reflection = Reflections(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(packageName),MethodAnnotationsScanner())
    val cds = reflection.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MinecraftCommand::class.java)
    if(cds.size != 0) {
        plugin.logger.info { "Registered ${cds.size} Commands." }
        cds.forEach {
            println(it.declaringClass.`package`.toString())
        }
    }
```

Any help would be Amazing thank you so much.